# 2004 Accord 4 Cyl Won't Start

Tags: starting, accord, cranks-wont-run

I have an 04 Accord that wont start. There have been two times the past month or so when it was like -20 degrees out and I had to jump it to start. The other day, its like 40 degrees, and it wont start. I'm thinking, well it must be the battery. So I buy a new battery and that doesn't solve the issue either. I had the battery tested and its good--checked all the connections/grounds. All my dash lights/radio work. The wipers work, albeit a bit slow. Replaced the starter relay--still no luck. Any thoughts? Here's a video of what it's doing: https://streamable.com/yh1nr

Comment: How many miles on the vehicle?

Comment: Sounds like it has no compression, maybe the timing belt broke.

Comment: @Moab It's a 2.4 so a chain. Agree on the compression. Time to do a compression test.